# Load data in store in Activate Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

I have a store:

```
{
     xtype : 'combobox',
     name : 'agent_id',
     itemId : 'agent_id',
     anchor : '98%',
     fieldLabel : 'Agent List',
     store : Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     storeId : 'special',
     fields : ['id', 'name']
     }),
    displayField : 'name',
    valueField : 'id'
}
```

I want add data in `activate()` function

I've tried but it's till not work

```
     activate : function() {            
    var store2 = this.down('#agent_id').getStore();
    var data = [];
    var value = {
            id : '1', name : 'Giám sát bán hàng'
    };
    data.push(value);
    store2.loadData(Ext.encode(data));
}
```

Someone help me!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to encode the data. It should be fine just sending it in as is.

```
activate: function() {
    var store = Ext.getStore('special'),
        data = [],
        value = {
            id: '1', name: 'Giám sát bán hàng'
        };
    data.push(value);
    store.loadData(data);
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't work, I've read about loadData() but thank u!